# Query from oracle doesn't work in SSIS

Tags: sql, oracle, ssis, etl

For Some reason this query doesn't work in SSIS

```
Select 
    IDLOGARCHIVOS, 
    NOMBREARCHIVO, 
    FECHACREACION 
from 
   ATEN_TDCMARK.LOGARCHIVOS 
where 
    trunc(FECHACREACION, 'DDD') = trunc(sysdate, 'DDD')
```

But when I tested in Toad works great what am I doing wrong? Is there a different way to treat dates? And I know that the problem it's related with the comparison of dates because when I remove this condition the query returns values

Comment: exactly what error it is showing ?

Comment: doesn't throw an error only doesn't bring records

Comment: can you test the query without the "where" part so we can be sure the problem is on the  trunc(sysdate, 'DDD')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First To solve my problem I need to modify `NS_LANG` in oracle registry on my machine locate at `(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\HOME0)`. Then I restart Machine and base on the answer of @Ben I modified my query and works in the etl  OF SSIS

```
Select 
    IDLOGARCHIVOS, 
    NOMBREARCHIVO, 
    FECHACREACION 
from 
   ATEN_TDCMARK.LOGARCHIVOS 
where 
    trunc(FECHACREACION, 'DDD') = trunc(sysdate, 'DDD')
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in Toad? I would have expected it to fail due to `to_date(sysdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy')`. You're trying to convert a date into a date, which Oracle normally raises an error on.

What you seem to want to do is [`truncate`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_date.php) the date to include year, month and day only, i.e. no time component.

This would be `trunc(sysdate, 'DD')`. `trunc(sysdate)` would return the same value as `'DD'` and it's synonyms are the default, but it's nice to be explicit.

Are you doing the same with your column `FECHACREACION`? If not and it's a character can I recommend that you store it as a date?

Comment: the problem is that I store the date with the hours and minuts, so the convertion that i made is to format the date and compare only the dates without the hours. But the query works

Answer (score 0):

for system date you have to use GETDATE() function in ssis in place of sysdate..

[for more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139875.aspx)

Comment: if you have convert it accordingly then what error you were getting?

Comment: I believe the OP meant that the Execute SQL task is actually using an Oracle database as its source. So he should use Oracle SQL, not TSQL. But this isn't obvious from the question so I may be wrong.